# Getting error while redirect to the home page in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I was trying to restrict logged in user to access login page using following code

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react"; import { Route }
 from "react-router-dom"; import { Redirect } from "react-router-dom";

 const UserLayoutRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => {  
 const [loggedIn, setLoggedIn] = useState(null);   useEffect(() => {
    if (localStorage.getItem("cachedValue") !== null) {
      setLoggedIn(true);
    }   }, []);   return loggedIn ? (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={matchProps => (
        <div className="App">
          <section className="user-page">
            <div className="">
              <div className="">
                <Component {...matchProps} />
              </div>
            </div>
          </section>
        </div>
      )}
    />   ) : (
    <Redirect to="/"  />   ); };

 export default UserLayoutRoute;
```

With this code page keep on loading and its not rendering anything.

I also posted this issue in GitHub https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/17514

Comment: Does this code run when you hit "/"?

Comment: @aksappy No this is only run when we acess page like /login, /signup/, /resetpassword but whole application is not working I am trying to access other URLs also (its only loading....loading.... )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that maybe you can try other approach like this

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';

const PrivateRouteComponent = ({ component: Component, isAuth, ...rest }) => (
  <Route
    {...rest}
    render={props => (
      isAuth
        ? <Component {...props} />
        : <Redirect to="/login" />
    )}
  />
);

PrivateRouteComponent.propTypes = {
  component: PropTypes.any.isRequired,
  isAuth: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
};

export default PrivateRouteComponent;
```

And in the case the routes

```
<Switch>
        <PrivateRouteComponent exact path="/" component={**ComponentName**} isAuth={isAuth} />
</Switch>
```

For the case that the isAuth props maybe you can change that for your condition

Comment: Thanks for the reply, this approach is not working, any how i am just trying to redirect logged in users to home page when they try to access /login page.. please help me achieve this